# What are the implications of A::B class name in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module, namespaces

I have a class Entity and inside this class I used to have an inner class called Config.

```rb
class Entity
 class Config
 end
end
```

The Config class has grown quite big so I decided to take it out into its own file. However, I still wanted to retain the namespace so I prefixed the Config class with an Entity:: leaving me with two class in two different files like so.

```rb
 #In entity.rb file
 class Entity
   require 'entity_config.rb'
 end

 #In entity_config.rb file
 class Entity::Config
 end
```

Now I'm able to instantiate config with Entity::Config.new

However, I don't understand the implications of namespacing the class name like that. Can somebody explain to me what really happens here?

Comment: Does the code actually work exactly as you've posted it? I would expect class `Entity` to have to exist before you write `class Entity::Config` so I would have thought doing the `require` before defining `Entity` would cause `NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Entity`?

Comment: Oops, you're right the require is inside the Entity class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `class Something` the `Something` you're providing is the name of a constant so providing the name using the `::` operator is equivalent to opening the outer class first and creating an inner class that way. The `::` operator is just a way to access a constant within a class or module from outside of that class or module. e.g. something like this is completely valid:

```
class Outer
  class Inner
  end

  class Inner::EvenMoreInner
  end
end

class Outer::Inner::EvenMoreInner::InnerMost
end
```

Notice, you can't just write `class Some::New::Class::Hierarchy` and have all the containing classes created automatically. i.e. `Some::New::Class` must exist first. This is why I queried the exact order of the code you've written in my comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks for a simple concise answer!